# How can I make templated operator deduce correct return type?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I want two orthogonal types A and B so that I can write

```
A a = b1 * b2; // b1,b2 of type B
B b = a1 * a2; // a1,a2 of type A
```

The data they share is the same, so I attempted some policy-based design. [Some code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b955a4adae46b0d):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct isA {};
struct isB {};

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
    int _data;

    template<typename U>
    myClass<U> operator * ( const myClass<T>& other );
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
myClass<U> myClass<T>::operator * ( const myClass<T>& other )
{
    // just an idea, will not be needed if correct instanciation
    static_assert( std::is_same<U,T>::value, "cannot return same type" );
   // ... here, some code
}


int main()
{
    myClass<isA> a1,a2;
    myClass<isB> b = a1 * a2;
}
```

This fails with:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:26:25: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are
'myClass<isA>' and 'myClass<isA>')
    myClass<isB> b = a1 * a2;
main.cpp:12:16: note: candidate: 'template<class U> myClass<U> myClass<T>::operator*(const myClass<T>&) [with U = U; T = isA]'
  myClass<U> operator * ( const myClass<T>& other );
 main.cpp:12:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 main.cpp:26:27: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'
```

What I understand is that it fails because its only the function arguments that are used by the compiler to generate the instanciation, not the return type. Thus the compiler cannot generate the correct instanciation for the operator.

My question (pretty simple): how can I implement this operator ?

There is no template specialization required here, the behavior is the same with the two types (but other functions - not shown here - will have a specific implementation for each of the types). But I want to enforce the fact that that you cannot do: `A a = a1 * a2;`

Side note: couldn't find any question with this topic, if you find one, please link!

Comment: @Some programmer dude ('bout the edit) Mmmh, okay, but std::is_same is only C++11...

Comment: Same remark. [c++] on its own means "current version", if OP only has access to C++11 that should be visible in the tags.

Comment: C++11 (at least) should be considered the baseline these days. Unless you ask about something specific regarding the C++11 standard, just use `c++` as tag.

Comment: @Some programmer dude agree, eventually.

Comment: Are there exactly two versions, a and b? or are there potentially multiples?

Comment: @Caleth Only two types, yes. You have some suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it as two (non-template) free functions. If the implementation is exactly the same, these can specify the return type for a shared implementation.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename Out, typename In>
    MyClass<Out> times( const MyClass<In> & lhs, const MyClass<In> & rhs)
    {
        // shared code here
    }
}

myClass<isA> operator * ( const myClass<isB>& lhs, const myClass<isB>& rhs )
{ return detail::times<isA>(lhs, rhs); }

myClass<isB> operator * ( const myClass<isA>& lhs, const myClass<isA>& rhs )
{ return detail::times<isB>(lhs, rhs); }
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trait that maps `isA` to `isB`, and `isB` to `isA`.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename>
    struct myClassTraits;

    template<>
    struct myClassTraits<isA>
    {
        using other_type = isB;
    };

    template<>
    struct myClassTraits<isB>
    {
        using other_type = isA;
    };
}

template<typename T>
struct myClass
{
    int _data;

    using times_t = myClass<typename detail::myClassTraits<T>::other_type>;

    times_t operator * ( const myClass& other );
};
```

Comment: Nice idea too. I can't really see a clear advantage over your other answer. Which one would you choose ? At present, I will probably accept the other one, as I find it a bit "clearer".

Comment: I'd go with this one if most of a whole bunch of operations are identically implemented, but result in the "other" type. I'd lean toward the other answer by default, and use that for operations that have different implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately C++ doesn't use return type to deduce template parameters (some other languages can do it), so you can do nothing with the template.

However to make

```
A a = b1 * b2; // b1,b2 of type B
```

working you may implement implicit conversion constructor so that first you'll get type `B` as a result of multiplication operator and then it will be cast to `A` type:

```
template <typename U>
myClass(const myClass<U>& other)  {} // copy conversion constructor
template <typename U>
myClass(myClass<U>&& other)  {} // move conversion constructor
```

so that

```
A a = b1 * b2;
```

will be equivalent to

```
A a = A(b1 * b2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but can't make this work, [see here](https://ideone.com/iSvXLZ) (Coliru seems down at present). I had to add a default constructor, but even with that, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @kebs you need to make operator* returning value of the same type as operands: https://ideone.com/QmtyfH

Comment: @DmitryGordon: No, he doesn't need the return type to be the same as the input type.  He does need some policy-setting object that can appear in the return type of the `operator*`, if `operator*` is to be a template.

Comment: Yes, from the comments to the question I see that it is needed only for two types. But from the original question I thought that there may be more than two types that need to be convertible to each other